# Reaction of alkenes with bromine in presence of sodium chloride

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

> Consider the following reaction
>            $$\ce{CH3\bond{-}CH\bond{=}CH2 ->T[$\ce{Br2}$/$\ce{NaCl}$]?}$$

What would be the product(s) for this reaction? I am confused because there are two nucleophiles here, $\ce{Br-}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$. So, there are two alternatives for the second step. Let me explain what I am saying.

First of all, the $\pi$-electrons will attack an electrophile which in this case is a $\ce{Br+}$ which is obtained form polarisation of the $\ce{Br\bond{-}Br}$ and it is added to the less substituted carbon, which complies with Markovnikov's rule, forming the carbocation below:
 $$\ce{CH3\bond{-}CH+\bond{-}CH2\bond{-}Br}$$

Now the carbocation will be attacked by a nucleophile. There are 2 nucleophiles in this problem, as I have stated earlier.
So, my question is which one of them will attack the carbocation and subsequently what will be the product? Will it be only 1,2-dibromopropane or only 1-bromo-2-chloropropane or a mixture of both? Please give the reasons.

Answer (score 9):

The first step is $\ce{Br-Br}$ approaching the pi-cloud, being polarized, loosing a $\ce{Br^{-}}$ to form a 3-cyclic bromonium cation.  Given solubility and reactively inert solvent, $\ce{Br^{-}}$ (large poor nucleophile) competes with $\ce{Cl^{-}}$ (smaller, better nucleophile) for ring-opening capture.  Now factor in relative concentrations.  Now factor in thermodynamics (reversibility, $\ce{Cl^{-}}$ wins for the stronger $\ce{C-Cl}$ bond) versus kinetics (smaller $\ce{Cl^{-}}$ vs. initial tight ion pair rapidly collapsing to product).  Temperature probably makes a product ratio difference, too.

If your linear ion intermediate is controlling, the $\ce{Cl}$ comes in at the 2-position by default.  If my cyclic ion intermediate is controlling, the $\ce{Cl}$ comes in at the 1-position by steric hindrance. And if you do it in water, you get halohydrin byproducts.

Keep the reaction way from light or you will get radical abstraction and allylic substitution.

Comment: Which product/reaction pathway is major? Bromine or chlorine addition?